# Groupby Pandas & Weight Time Series

Tags: pandas, group-by, apply, weighted

i'm trying to compute the weights for each time series or data values by the groupby of "plant_name" and "month" and I cannot see the solution. I have data that looks like this -

```
   plant_name  month  adjusted_wspd
0   ARIZONA I      1           7.62
1   ARIZONA I      2           7.37
2   ARIZONA I      3           6.72
3   ARIZONA I      4           6.67
4   ARIZONA I      5           7.07
5   ARIZONA I      6           7.53
6   ARIZONA I      7           8.09
7   ARIZONA I      8           8.83
8   ARIZONA I      9           9.41
9   ARIZONA I     10           9.44
10  ARIZONA I     11           8.92
11  ARIZONA I     12           8.37
12  CAETITE I      1           7.10
13  CAETITE I      2           7.27
14  CAETITE I      3           7.26
```

I have tried writing a function and using "apply" to the defined function but I get an incorrect solution that looks like this because the function is probably doing the math incorrectly:

```
ARIZONA  I  1        1.0
            2        1.0
            3        1.0
            4        1.0
            5        1.0
            6        1.0
            7        1.0
            8        1.0
            9        1.0
            10       1.0
            11       1.0
            12       1.0
CAETITE I   1        1.0
            2        1.0
            3        1.0
```

My code looks like this:

```
def my_agg(x):
    names = {'Weigths_WSPD': (x['adjusted_wspd'] )/x['adjusted_wspd'].sum()}
    return pd.Series(names, index=['Weights_WSPD'])
dfmm.groupby(["plant_name", "month"]).apply(my_agg)
```

My answer should look like this in percent (%):

```
ARIZONA  I  1        7.93
            2        7.67
            3        7.00
            4        6.95
            5        7.36
            6        7.84
            7        8.42
            8        9.19
            9        9.80
            10       9.83
            11       9.29
            12       8.72
CAETITE I   1        33.82
            2        33.61
            3        33.56
```

thank you!

Comment: HI - thanks for your help. the expected result shown above is just done with excel. i understand how the answer is "1" but I don't know how to change the function to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform) sum on just `plant_name` not `plant_name` and `month`:

```
df['Weigths_WSPD'] = (
        df['adjusted_wspd'] /
        df.groupby('plant_name')['adjusted_wspd'].transform('sum') *
        100
).round(2)
```

```
   plant_name  month  adjusted_wspd  Weigths_WSPD
0   ARIZONA I      1           7.62          7.93
1   ARIZONA I      2           7.37          7.67
2   ARIZONA I      3           6.72          7.00
3   ARIZONA I      4           6.67          6.95
4   ARIZONA I      5           7.07          7.36
5   ARIZONA I      6           7.53          7.84
6   ARIZONA I      7           8.09          8.42
7   ARIZONA I      8           8.83          9.19
8   ARIZONA I      9           9.41          9.80
9   ARIZONA I     10           9.44          9.83
10  ARIZONA I     11           8.92          9.29
11  ARIZONA I     12           8.37          8.72
12  CAETITE I      1           7.10         32.82
13  CAETITE I      2           7.27         33.61
14  CAETITE I      3           7.26         33.56
```

---

If a `Series` is necessary:

```
s = df.set_index(['plant_name', 'month'])
s = (
        s['adjusted_wspd'] /
        s.groupby(level=0)['adjusted_wspd'].transform('sum') *
        100
).round(2).rename('Weigths_WSPD')
```

```
plant_name  month
ARIZONA I   1         7.93
            2         7.67
            3         7.00
            4         6.95
            5         7.36
            6         7.84
            7         8.42
            8         9.19
            9         9.80
            10        9.83
            11        9.29
            12        8.72
CAETITE I   1        32.82
            2        33.61
            3        33.56
Name: Weigths_WSPD, dtype: float64
```

---

DataFrame constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'plant_name': {0: 'ARIZONA I', 1: 'ARIZONA I', 2: 'ARIZONA I',
                   3: 'ARIZONA I', 4: 'ARIZONA I', 5: 'ARIZONA I',
                   6: 'ARIZONA I', 7: 'ARIZONA I', 8: 'ARIZONA I',
                   9: 'ARIZONA I', 10: 'ARIZONA I', 11: 'ARIZONA I',
                   12: 'CAETITE I', 13: 'CAETITE I', 14: 'CAETITE I'},
    'month': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10,
              10: 11, 11: 12, 12: 1, 13: 2, 14: 3},
    'adjusted_wspd': {0: 7.62, 1: 7.37, 2: 6.72, 3: 6.67, 4: 7.07, 5: 7.53,
                      6: 8.09, 7: 8.83, 8: 9.41, 9: 9.44, 10: 8.92, 11: 8.37,
                      12: 7.1, 13: 7.27, 14: 7.26}
})
```